# How to unblock the program from the group policy in Android Studio for a Flutter application?

Tags: android, windows, flutter, dart, group-policy

I am trying to create a new application in flutter using Andriod Studio but the following error is shown:

**This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.**

Not sure if this will help but The AVD manager is also not shown in the tools bar!

Any idea how can I fix it in a Windows 10 OS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If your computer disables the device driver, you can change the setup to repair this problem. Here are the steps:

Step 1: Press the Windows + R keys to open the Run dialog. Then you should type gpedit.msc and click OK to open the Group Policy window.

Step 2: Expand User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System. In the right pane, navigate to Don’t run specified Windows applications and double-click it.

Step 3: Then click the Show button.

Step 4: Remove the target program or application from the disallowed list and click OK.

[Source](https://www.minitool.com/news/this-program-is-blocked-by-group-policy.html)

Comment: I have tried but it did not work, still have that error!

Comment: i am getting the same error , did you  found solution